# Redshift COPY and create table automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Is there not a way to automatically create an **internal** table in Redshift and then move data into it with COPY? Can I not use the metadata stored on AWS Glue Data Catalog to create it?

Right now as I understand it, one has to manually write SQL to create a table and then run COPY to move data into the table.

Edit: My problem is the table creation. For me to run COPY a table must already exist. Can i create this table using the existing GLUE metadata? Or can i only write SQL by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automate the data movement from Glue catalog to Redshift table you can use AWS Glue to achieve it. Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-redshift.html) for more information.

Once you have your Glue jobs ready you can always schedule them to run at some point of time everyday.

Comment: are you using redshift and you want only internal table? if you want an internal table which should be created by accessing Glue metadata then it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Automatic table creation can be achieved using the below workaround.

1. Create table definition by running the Glue Crawler.
2. Create an external database in redshift pointing to the glue database.

   CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA my_ext_db FROM DATA CATALOG DATABASE 'my_glue_db' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam:::role/my-redshift-role';
3. Now create a redshift table using the below command

   CREATE TABLE my_internal_db.my_table AS Select * from my_ext_db.my_table;
4. you can now run the copy into command on this empty table
   my_internal_db.my_table.